# High performance string hashing function in Java/Scala

Tags: java, performance, scala, hash

Looking for a high-performance String hashing functions in Java/Scala - something faster than functions from MurmurHash family, doesn't need to be cryptographically strong, only distribute well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you checked so far? A quick search reveals this: https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java

Comment: Well... If you need something similar to MurmerHash but faster then you can look at CityHash. CityHash is around 2x faster but beware it is under active refinement and is not recommended for production use yet. Murmur is fast enough and since it is used in so many popular projects, it has efficient and refined implementations in various languages so what's wrong with staying put with MurmurHash for now ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes... OP's question does not indicate much effort, but `lz4-java` is a `lz4` implementation which is a `compression` algorithm and not for `Hashing`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Just check the page linked to a *bit* more carefully.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I did it the first time itself, but I think it would have been better if you have mentioned that you are talking about XXHash ( Original this - https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/ based on SMHasher - https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/SMHasher ) and whose Java implementation can be found in https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java . Also... we can not be sure about the performance of this Java implementation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Checked the link carefully. Where are the **string** hash functions there?

Comment: @apangin Are you implying that the streaming `byte[]`-oriented API would be impossible to use in a performant way? You may be right, haven't checked. Anyway, the only point I made was that OP should have mentioned what he found so far and why it didn't work for him.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I will pick the complete Java port, but both xxHash and CityHash appear faster than MurmurHash. I wonder what collisions comparison is like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find very fast hash function implementations for Java, which BTW account internal String implementation (`char[]` array) to maximize speed, here: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Zero-Allocation-Hashing

Comment: Are you planning to port FarmHash soon?

Comment: @RenatBekbolatov no, I have no specific plans

Comment: Just for late readers of this thread, FarmHash is already implemented in Zero-Allocation Hashing.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest hashing algorithm that fits the bill presently seems to be [xxHash](https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/).  The lz4-java project contains an [implementation ported to Java](https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java/tree/master/src/java/net/jpountz/xxhash).  I don't know whether the Java implementation has been benchmarked against MurmurHash, though; performance optimizations in C++ don't always port to/from Java.  (In particular, xxHash contains more array access, so there could be non-negligible bounds-checking overhead.)

*Edit: it looks to me like it uses JNI to call the C++ implementation of xxHash, but JNI overhead is non-negligible, so the performance concerns remain.*

However, given that Scala [includes a MurmurHash function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3$), and that Java contains a faster default hash (about 2x) that is sorta-reasonably distributed sometimes, one does wonder whether it's really necessary.  For instance, `scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3` is about as fast as string creation from an array of bytes, and is twice as fast as that if you give it an array of bytes.

Comment: Bounds checking is regularly eliminated by the JIT compiler if you just take basic care to let it know you're not overstepping the limits.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Of course, but whether it is completely (or sufficiently) eliminated in any particular implementation of an algorithm is not certain.  (For example, steps of irregular sizes tends to confuse it.)  Hence the need for benchmarking, especially since MurmurHash is already quite fast.

Comment: Definitely benchmark, yes. But it's usually possible to add a little tweak to your loop which will assure the JIT compiler you're not overstepping the limit. Such as inserting a seemingly redundant `&& index < array.length` in the loop condition.